# Can I add substitute formula with another substitute formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, spreadsheet, substitution

X=numbers that go by performance

[image: []

Is it possible to add a substituted cell with another substituted cell?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B12,"x",1)+SUBSTITUTE(B25,"x",1)
```

Or would it be cell C12-C25? Please see image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(B12:B25,"x")
```

for D:

```
=COUNTIF(D12:D25,"x")*2
```

For F:

```
=COUNTIF(F12:F25,"x")*3
```

Comment: You're quick :)

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the formulas above would go into cells B27, D27, and F27, respectively. Also, columns C, E, and G would no longer be needed.

Comment: @BonnieMolnar please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for the excel help!